# ElasticSearch query to find records not matching

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a multiple records of type companies which is a nested json document saved in elastic search. Companies has the following structure,

```
{"companies" : [{
  "company" : {
    "manager" : [{
      "name" : "abc",
      "age" : "40"
    }],
    "employee_count" : "2300",
    "profit" : "10"
  },
  "company" : {
    "manager" : [{
      "name" : "def",
      "age" : "41"
    }],
    "employee_count" : "2200",
    "profit" : "10"
  },
  "company" : {
    "manager" : [{
      "name" : "ghi",
      "age" : "42"
    }],
    "employee_count" : "2100",
    "profit" : "10"
  }
}]
}
```

I need to find the count of companies records where NONE of company.manager.name is "abc".

I tried using the following query but it does not not work.

GET index/_search

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not" : [{
        "match" : {
          "company.manager.name" : "abc"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hey George, welcome to SO! When you say that your query doesn't work do you mean you are getting 0 results, an error message, or something else?

Comment: I provided answer, assuming you have defined proper mapping , but for a good elasticsearch question you should provide index def(setting and mapping), you sample docs , search query and expected outcome. please go through my answer and if it doesn't work please provide all this info, so that I can provide further help

Comment: @Nate i am getting all the records back as response.

Comment: hmm, I don't think I've been able to reproduce your index (I created an index for companies, bc mapping types are deprecated), but your query works in that scenario. Side note, you may want to user the [`_count/` API eventually](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the `nested` mapping, you need to mention the `nested` path  while querying your data, please refer [this official doc for sample nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-fields-array-objects)

**Your query should look like below which has `nested` path**

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "companies",  --> note this
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "company.manager.name": "abc"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right. i added the nested clause to the query with the proper path. however it returns all the records present under the index as response. i cannot provide more information about the mapping since i am using mocked data to post here. cannot share the actual data. The expected outcome is the count of 'companies' record that do not have a company with manager name 'abc'. so essentially count of 'companies' for which the field 'companies.company.manager.name' should not match 'abc'. i have shared the structure of one companies record above.

Comment: @George, looks like there is some issue with your sample document, I was not able to index it using the ```{
    "mappings" :{
     "properties" : {
      "companies" : {
       "type" : "nested"
      }
     }
    }
}``` mapping, can you please take this as reference and create sample doc like in your question?

Comment: @George, did you get a chance to look at my last comment?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count the number of elements, you should aggregate the data first based on that condition. Take a look to [this section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) of the official documentation of Elastic.